# jruby irb newline \r instead of \n

Tags: ruby, jruby, irb

Using jruby 9.1.2.0 irb I get ^M instead of \n when hitting the return key.

To reproduce:
Run jruby irb 
i.e. 
`java -jar jruby-complete-9.1.2.0-complete.jar -S irb`

```
> gets
enteranyinputhere
```

hit the enter or return key and observe

```
> gets
enteranyinputhere^M
```

when I expect

```
> gets
anyinputhere
=> "anyinputhere\n"
```

This makes it impossible to gets any input at all. It might have something to do with Mac inputting `\r` instead of `\n` when hitting enter

```
> gets("\r").chomp
foo^M=> "foo"
```

I also observed this issue with the latest jruby version 9.1.4.0

Comment: What version of the OS are you using? I can't reproduce that on my machine (OS X 10.11, JRuby 9.1.2.0). Is it possible your terminal has some odd setting?

Comment: I am also using iterm but also reproduced it on bash

Comment: iTerm is your terminal. `bash` is your shell. These two are only tangentally related.

Comment: I meant default mac terminal

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this by pasting in text from another Terminal window and fixed it by disabling the "Paste newlines as carriage returns" option under *Input* of the Advanced tab of the preferences.

Comment: The preferences for which piece of software?  Built-in Terminal app has no Advanced tab (for me, at least)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Under "Profiles" select the one you're using, then switch to the "Advanced" tab there. This is in the stock Terminal app.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me

Comment: Is it possible you have some really wonky `stty` settings? `stty -icrnl` causes the `^M` behaviour for me, `stty icrnl` fixes it.

Comment: tried toggling the `stty icrnl` but that doesn't seem to be the issue either

Comment: Can you reproduce it on other machines? Is this a recent phenomenon?